# Can anyone make Chrome and/or Chromium post version 78 work over ssh X forwarding?

Tags: google-chrome, ssh, xorg

Since version 79, Chrome and Chromium fail to work over ssh X forwarding. Forwarding is indeed working on my setup, and I use Firefox, VS Code and Eclipse seamlessly over the X forwarded tunnel. But not Chrome nor Chromium. My setup is an Ubuntu 19.04 machine ssh-ing into an Ubuntu 20.04 virtual machine on VirtualBox.

This is not related to the earlier [--use-gl=swiftshader](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1051443/cant-get-google-chrome-to-x11-forward-but-firefox-does) issue, but appears to be a [known bug](https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/23330705?hl=en), from version 79 on, and unresolved to this day.

On starting Chrome `google-chrome`, a big grey box appears and the only working option is to quit, with the terminal showing

```
[0720/135908.663897:ERROR:nacl_helper_linux.cc(308)] NaCl helper process running without a sandbox!
Most likely you need to configure your SUID sandbox correctly
```

On starting Chromium `chromium-browser`, no window appears and the application exits, with the terminal showing

```
X11 connection rejected because of wrong authentication.
[7370:7370:0720/140137.070385:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(1469)] Unable to open X display.
```

[The accepted work around is](https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/23330705?hl=en)

```
cc -shared -o XlibNoSHM.so XlibNoSHM.c
  LD_PRELOAD='libdl.so ./XlibNoSHM.so' chromium
```

against [XlibNoSHM.c](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?att=1;bug=949440;filename=XlibNoSHM.c;msg=10)

The compile is fine, but `LD_PRELOAD='libdl.so ./XlibNoSHM.so' chromium`
fails

```
ERROR: ld.so: object 'libdl.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored.
X11 connection rejected because of wrong authentication.
[3423:3423:0720/143727.259731:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(1469)] Unable to open X display.
```

while `LD_PRELOAD='/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so ./XlibNoSHM.so' google-chrome`
runs but opens no windows, with output

```
[0720/143831.101539:ERROR:nacl_helper_linux.cc(308)] NaCl helper process running without a sandbox!
Most likely you need to configure your SUID sandbox correctly
```

The fix does not work at all against Chrome.

- Can anyone find a way to run the latest Chrome over ssh X forwarding? Second prize would be Chromium over X?
- Do the error messages regarding SUID suggest a different problem and solution?

[... I have tried `--disable-setuid-sandbox` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24237933/compile-execute-chromium-failed-due-to-suid-sandbox-issue) but that does not help. Still the grey blank window.